# find number of class after finding element by its xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i want to get the number of class of 1 element
i have this code for locating an element:

```
url = '/v/پیش-فروش-متریال-متفاوت_پیش-فروش_تهران_افسریه_دیوار/AY7nRuql'
boz = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@href, '"+ url+ "')]")
```

then i get its class by the code below:

```
print(boz.get_attribute('class'))
```

and i get this output: kt-post-card kt-post-card--outlined kt-post-card--has-chat

i want to get the number of the class in the page because there are 24 class like the class above

Comment: actually i want to get number of class of this url in all of the page
i have 24 of the same classes and I want to know the number of matched class with this element
like find element by xpath that contains this class kt-post-card kt-post-card--outlined kt-post-card--has-chat [0 to 23]
i want the number of [0 to 23]

Answer (score 0):

You can store the elements into a list and get the length of the list.

```py
boz = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@href, '"+ url+ "')]")
print(len(boz))
print(boz[0].get_attribute('class'))
```

Comment: actually i want to get number of class of this url in all of the page i have 24 of the same classes and I want to know the number of matched class with this element like find element by xpath that contains this class kt-post-card kt-post-card--outlined kt-post-card--has-chat [0 to 23] i want the number of [0 to 23]

Comment: I am sorry, but I still didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the below `xpath`, and `find_elements`:

I believe,

```
//*[contains(@href, '//*[contains(@href, '/v/')]')]
```

represent the 24 classes that you are looking.

**Code :-**

```
all = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@href, '//*[contains(@href, '/v/') ]')]")
for a in all:
    print(a.get_attribute('class'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try a couple things...

1. Have you tried

   ```
   url = '/v/پیش-فروش-متریال-متفاوت_پیش-فروش_تهران_افسریه_دیوار/AY7nRuql'
   boz = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@href, '"+ url+ "')]")
   #                        ^ note I added S to get all of them
   print(len(boz))
   ```

   You didn't provide the URL so I can't check to see if this will work or not but I think there's a chance it might but you will have to check.
2. If #1 doesn't work, you should be able to do this

   ```
   url = '/v/پیش-فروش-متریال-متفاوت_پیش-فروش_تهران_افسریه_دیوار/AY7nRuql'
   boz = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@href, '"+ url+ "')]")
   classes = boz.get_attribute('class')
   elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='" + classes + "']")
   print(len(elements))
   ```